# Permutations of objects into bins

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

A question asks: *to compute how many ways are there to put 5 bottles (indistinguishable) and 8 cans (indistinguishable) into 13 bins which are numbered thus are distinguishable. Also the order of putting the rubbish into the bin is important and only one item is put into a bin at the time.*

I have tried to lower the number of bins to 2, 3 and 4 and compute all the posibilites manually and later try to figure out the formula but unfortunetly with no success.

If someone is able to help I be vary grateful.

Comment: When you say the order matters, do you mean that placing all the bottles first and the all the cans is different from placing the cans first followed by the bottles, even if every can and every bottle winds up in the same bin?

Comment: As a related question:  say we only had two bottles (and no cans).  If we put  the first bottle in the first bin, and then the second bottle in the second bin, is that different from putting the first bottle in the second bin and the second bottle in the first?

Answer (score 0):

Say the number of ways you can place bottles into bins is $B$, and the number of ways to place cans into bins is $C$ For each possible placement of bottles to bins, there are $C$ distinct ways to place the cans such that all arrangements are different. This means that you have $B \cdot C$ different ways of placing cans and bottles into bins. Now, to calculate $B$ and $C$, you can use the  classic "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" approach, where the cans are the stars and the bins are the bars.